# Need help loading jquery plugin Wordpress 3.8

Tags: wordpress, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to incorporate this plugin - [Glide.js](http://jedrzejchalubek.com/glide/)  ---- into my wordpress homepage. Please have a look at the README file for instruction reference.

Following is what the custom page template that I created looks like *

```
<?php
/**
* The template used for displaying frontpage content
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
* @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
*/
?>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/glide/css/style.css"/>

<?php
function my_init() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js', false, '1.3.2', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

        // load a JS file from my theme: js/theme.js
        wp_enqueue_script('my_script', get_bloginfo('/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen') . 'glide/jquery.glide.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
     }
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');
?>

</head>

    <div class="front-content"> 
                <div class="slider">
                         <ul class="slides">
                           <li class="slide"><img alt="" src="http://mydomain.com/wp-content/images/hosting.png"/></li>
                           <li class="slide"><img alt="" src="http://mydomain.com/wp-content/images/web-development.png"/></li>
                           <li class="slide"><img alt="" src="http://mydomain.com/wp-content/images/domains.png"/></li>
                         </ul>
                        </div>

      </div><!-- .front-content -->
```

I am not exactly sure where I'm going wrong in my code, but basically the output I get is 3 slide images in consecutive list format, ie. rather than the actual slideshow.

The entire output would also be off-center and displays slightly off the page.

Accordign to the README, I am also not sure how to list/create the API instance, or use suggested script to init.

---- Where am I going wrong :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid deregistering jQuery.

Add this to your functions.php file

```
function my_enqueue_glide() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'glide', get_template_directory_uri() . '/glide/css/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-glide', get_template_directory_uri() . '/glide/jquery.glide.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_glide' );
```

Also remove the function and action hook from the page template shown in your question as well as the stylesheet

Comment: Thanks.- How do I call for the javascript from template file

Comment: following is what I used:                                      <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.slider').glide(){

$.post("http://mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/functions.php");

)}                                                                             That first part is I'm told to use as init judging from the readme, I'm still getting static images tho

Comment: No worries! got it to work- thanks. I'm off to tweaking the CSS a bit, so that it can load the style correctly, but the jQuery is being called, and that's great. Thanks for putting me in the right direction :D